# How to escape colons in category names for use by DPL?

Tags: mediawiki, dpl

I have several categories in a mediawiki which have colons in the name.  With DPL, when I try either

category=Foo:bar

or

linksto=Category:Foo:bar

I get no results, even though that category when viewed actually shows several hundred pages.  I presume it is due to the colons in the category name.  Is there some way to escape the colon in a way that makes DPL happy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only working solution seems to be to use the categorymatch argument, rather than the category argument, using the % wildcard in place of the colons.

So instead of

|category=Foo:bar

use

|categorymatch=Foo%bar

Answer (score -1):

You should use colon before the category name, for example:

```
[[:Category:foo]]
```

And this will work!.

Comment: That's how you link to a Category within MediaWiki.  I'm asking about DPL queries.

Comment: Ah, Since DPL uses Perl syntax; you can use backslash "\" to escape the colon. See this for more info:  http://semeb.com/dpldemo/index.php?title=DPL:Manual_-_General_Usage_and_Invocation_Syntax#Characters_with_special_meaning